# Question for song

Tags: lyrics, songs

One Month - Tegan and Sara

Video Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIwv1XdTTHc&t=32s

Q1. What does she say in 0:32 ?

Comment: I can't make out about a third of the words, generally.

Comment: Welcome to SE! This type of question is probably considered off-topic for English Language & Usage. Also, what research have done? Have you tried looking up the lyrics online?

Comment: miltonaut thanks for your comment! But I'm not fluent in English so
I couldn't understand some of your words. Sorry.
Yeah I tried to find out lyrics, but I couldn't sure about that part (0:32)

Comment: I think the lyrics on the internet doesn't seem to be correct
That's why I asked people here this question

Answer (score 0):

"An old man behind his walls
And all day long he's fielding calls"

Source: https://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/t/tegan_and_sara/one_month.html#!

Comment: I don't think so..That's why I ask people here
She said "All day Uxxxx he's fielding calls" in my opinion